# How to update firebase-messaging-sw.js in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

[service workets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrnBg.png)

After change the firebase-messaging-sw.js and refresh the page, but firebase-messaging-sw.js won't update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Chrome, right-click to inspect. Go to 'Application' tab, and click on Service Workers on the left panel where you can configure the settings for service workers. This should also work on Firefox.

The default for me was offline, so I change it to **Update on reload**. You can also choose to manually Unregister or Update the file.

[image]

found my answer on: https://love2dev.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-a-service-worker/